# How to highlight JSON and Javascript syntax with Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, rubygems, syntax-highlighting

I've found this gem called [syntax](http://syntax.rubyforge.org/api/) which is pretty cool, but it doesn't seem to generate syntax for javascript and json...

Is there a good way to highlight the syntax for these formats directly from ruby?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good run down of Ruby syntax highlighters [here](http://doblock.com/articles/a-whistle-stop-tour-of-syntax-highlighting-and-markdown-solutions-for-rails)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here after some Google searching.  The one library I've come up with at this point is Rouge: https://github.com/jneen/rouge